# Set initial size to LinearLayout that getting returned from BaseAdapter's getView method

Tags: android

I am trying to write a photo gallery that show images with GridView. Images are loaded from remote location and I want to show horizontal progress bar while images are loading. This part is working ok. I wrote custom adapter that is extended from BaseAdapter. In my getView method I am returning LinearLayout object which conteins ProgressBar object in it, which is getting replaced by ImageView when images loading finishes.

So here is my problem. Progress bars are thin(have small height) in comparison to ImageView objects. And what happens is when gallery activity starts I see lot of progress bars and then they are starting to "expand" (because images heights are larger than progress bars heights) and it's preety ugly. I want to set initial width and height to my LinearLayout object that I am returning in getView method.

Anyone can help me to implement this?

Here is my code:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(activity);

    // Some code here to set initial width and height to layout


    // This is my image loader that puts progress bar in layout, 
    // loads image then replaces progrssbar with image
    new LoadAndShowImage(imageUrl, layout, onClick, memCache).execute();

    return layout;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked question in other way and got answer. It is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9758132/608238)